# Very high flow in new replacement refrigerator water filter

Tags: water

No leaks or anything like that but the water really flies out when filling a glass. Used to be much slower. Is there any chance that water is bypassing the new filter? Water seems clear and tastes ok but I can fill a 16 oz glass of water in about 5 seconds...could it just be a high flow filter? It is rated at .8 gals per minute.

Comment: Was the old filter 12 years old? It's unlikely that the filter is bypassed if there's not a gigantic puddle on your floor, but how can we say for sure? You haven't even told us what fridge or filter you have.

Comment: Why did you replace  the old filter... Because it was clogged, perhaps?  Is it a quality branded filter that is the same size and correct fit for your old filter?

Comment: This is a seven year old Maytag fridge. The old filter was in place for about 8 months and like I said there is no leaked water with the new one being installed. I have never had one fill as fast with a new filter so I wondered if something was wrong...get it?

Comment: Hi! You were unable to leave a comment because you have a couple of unregistered user accounts. Please consider [registering](/help/why-register) one of them then [merge them](/help/merging-accounts) together, which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Comment: It is possible that the filter is not "high flow" but not filtering as good. Could be a standard filter vs possibly a charcoal filter. Some filters will take longer because they filter more contaminants from the water. A basic, cheapo, filter could possibly be just a cotton core, and not really filtering much other than larger particles. Do you know fridge model number, as well as the filter model you purchased? With a search of those, we might be able to tell if the filter is just a basic filter, and what came with the fridge was a multi-stage filter.